# How to compare these two strings representing a file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, io

I want to compare two strings that represent a file name:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = textBox1.Text;
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Cache", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    int Flag = 0;
    string dir = @"C:\Cache";
    string[] files1;
    int numFiles;
    files1 = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
    numFiles = files.Length;

    MessageBox.Show("Files searched : " + numFiles);
    Console.WriteLine("Files searched : " + numFiles + "<br>");
    foreach (string name in files1)
    {
       if (textBox1.Text.Substring(23,30) == files1.ToString()) // << this line
       {
           MessageBox.Show(name);
       }
   }
}
```

I have a question about how to do that, I am now comparing using this line:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Substring(23,30) == files1.ToString())
```

Where

```
textbox1 = "http://localhost:11806/ourwork.html" 
files1   = "D:\M.Tech\Dissertation 2\Cache\ourwork.html"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, Are you trying to compare two strings, two file names or are you trying to establish whether the two paths refer to the dame file? Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `files1` is an array of strings, whatever comparison you need to do, should be versus the `name` variable that represents individual file names contained in that array.

Answer (score 0):

It have put together some codes that will help you run this search on any file cache or directory on your machine.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    {
        List<string> searchResults = SearchCache(textBox1.Text, @"C:\Cache");

        foreach (string file in searchResults)
        {
            //MessageBox popup can be set up here if you like...
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found: {0}", file));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all matches to the file name in the search text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchText">The file path in the search text</param>
    /// <param name="cachePath">The cache path</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> SearchCache(string searchText, string cachePath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(cachePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("No. of files in cache: {0}", files.Length));

        List<string> searchResults = new List<string>();

        foreach (string file in files)
            if (AreFileReferencesSame(searchText, file))
                searchResults.Add(file);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("No. of matches: {0}", searchResults.Count));

        return searchResults;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the files referenced by a URL and the cache versions are the same
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">Url path</param>
    /// <param name="filePath">Cached file full path</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool AreFileReferencesSame(string url, string filePath)
    {
        //Extract the file names from both strings
        int lastIndexOfUrl = url.LastIndexOf("/");
        int lastIndexOfPath = filePath.LastIndexOf(@"\");

        //Move the marker one ahead if the placeholders are found
        lastIndexOfUrl = lastIndexOfUrl >= 0 ? lastIndexOfUrl + 1 : 0;
        lastIndexOfPath = lastIndexOfPath >= 0 ? lastIndexOfPath + 1 : 0;

        string urlFilename = url.Substring(lastIndexOfUrl).Trim();
        string diskFilename = filePath.Substring(lastIndexOfPath).ToString();

        if (urlFilename.Equals(diskFilename, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```